# Quantal -> Raring -> Saucy upgrade path, how?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently in chat we noticed some kind of oddity about the whole 12.10 > 13.04 > 13.10 upgrade path, where Raring will reach EOL before Quantal and how that will play out for us and for the users upgrading. Here is the response:

> While raring with be EOL and stop receiving updates before quantal is
>   in the same boat, I don't anticipate removing raring from the mirrors
>   until after quantal's EOL, to avoid any serious issues for people who
>   try to do the release hop from Q-R-S-T.

From here we can infer two things:

1. Raring will be EOL and Quantal not. Per our FAQ, **Raring questions should be closed** and push users to upgrade. Quantal is supported and on topic until April 2014.
2. There shouldn't be any questions about changing domains to `old-releases` while using/upgrading Raring, **which is a relief**.

> We should also be working on making sure that Q-T (bypassing R and S)
>   upgrade paths work, and be pushing users (via update-manager hints)
>   toward that direction.
>
> ... Adam

Fear my dear comrads... apparently the upgrade team plans to **allow users to jump releases** (I remember a question that says that you can't) for one time only. I would expect some questions about problems while doing this... oh well.

Then I received another mail with more information about the whole jumping releases:

> > We should also be working on making sure that Q-T (bypassing R and S)
> >     upgrade paths work, and be pushing users (via update-manager hints)
> >     toward that direction.
>
> That's in fact what we discsussed in the upgrade testing UDS session.
>   We need to make the five times more complicated [1] P → T upgrade work
>   anyway, this should almost automatically provide a working Q → T path
>   (we'll explicitly test this as well, of course).
>
> Martin
>
> [1] due to all those 12.04.* LTS enablement stacks

I don't have comments about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final response:

> This question came up a while ago on Ask Ubuntu, and Jorge asked me to help
>   respond to it:
>
> [How will people upgrade from 12.10 to later releases after 13.04 is EOL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368068/how-will-people-upgrade-from-12-10-to-14-04-after-13-04-is-eol/368099)
>
> I've just tuned the answer there to make it clearer that this method *will*
>   be used and supported for upgrades from 12.10.
>
> As Brian mentions, we can't really go straight from 12.10 to 14.04 because
>   13.04 goes EOL in January, and upgrades to 14.04 are only supported starting
>   in April - so while users of 12.10 will have security support until April,
>   they would also be completely unable to upgrade through the UI from January
>   until April and we don't want any remaining 12.10 users to have to scramble
>   to upgrade the very day that 14.04 is released.  So instead the supported
>   upgrade path will be 12.10->13.10->14.04, starting from January.
>
> Hope that helps,

So, this will be one time thingy. We could expect quirks in the upgrade... we will see.